# How to create independent objects

Tags: python, oop

I'm having a problem with two objects I created. I have a while loop getting some data. I save this data in an object and on each loop I want to see if my data has changed. If its true I save the data on a log. The problem is that when I refresh my actVar my prevVar is getting this changed too. This is my code:

I tried to use the copy() function with no success

```py
uvcomsSup = UVCEComsCtrl_SupportData()
uvcomsAntSup = UVCEComsCtrl_SupportData()

while 1:
    try:        
        uvcomsSup = getUVComsSupport(OrigAddress, UVComsDestAddress)            
        print(uvcomsSup)
        print("________________________")
        print(uvcomsAntSup)               
        print(uvcomsSup is uvcomsAntSup)
        if (uvcomsSup != uvcomsAntSup):
            uvcomsAntSup = copy.copy(uvcomsSup)                      
            logFile.addSupportData(str(uvcomsSup))   
        sleep(1)
    except Exception as err:
        print("Error inesperado:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        print(err)
```

When I print this two objects (I have an **eq** method and **str** method) I see the same values. I just enter in the if condition the first time.

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: Try to use deepcopy instead of copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot run your code so I cannot see the whole picture.

However I can see you are returning [a shallow copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.copy) of `ucomsSup`, which retains references to the original object thus modifying it.

Try using [a deep copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) instead.

```py
uvcomsSup = UVCEComsCtrl_SupportData()
uvcomsAntSup = UVCEComsCtrl_SupportData()

while 1:
    try:        
        uvcomsSup = getUVComsSupport(OrigAddress, UVComsDestAddress)            
        print(uvcomsSup)
        print("________________________")
        print(uvcomsAntSup)               
        print(uvcomsSup is uvcomsAntSup)
        if (uvcomsSup != uvcomsAntSup):
            uvcomsAntSup = copy.deepcopy(uvcomsSup) ## Create deep copy                 
            logFile.addSupportData(str(uvcomsSup))   
        sleep(1)
    except Exception as err:
        print("Error inesperado:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        print(err)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python docs say:

> copy(x) Return a shallow copy of x.
>
> A shallow copy constructs a new
> compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references
> into it to the objects found in the original.

Try using copy.deepcopy(x) instead.

```
uvcomsAntSup = copy.deepcopy(uvcomsSup)
```

> copy.deepcopy(x) Return a deep copy of x.
>
> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively,
> inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

Read more about this: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html